# Altair scatter plot: Instead of size = count, can I have size = percent or proportion or something?

Tags: scatter-plot, altair

I'm making a scatter plot of how satisfied people are, by age:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('d2_age', bin = True),
    alt.Y('3_satisfied'),
    size = 'count()'
)
```

But, instead of having the size of each mark be an absolute count, I want to have it be the proportion or percent of that age range. So instead of seeing that 300 people in their 60s rated their satisfaction at a 7, you'd see that 50% of people in their 60s did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible to do, but for this kind of calculation you must do your binning and aggregation via [transforms](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html) rather than via encoding shortcuts.

Here is an example of the type of chart you're asking about:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'd2_age': rng.normal(40, 10, 100),
    '3_satisfied': rng.randint(1, 11, 100)
})

alt.Chart(df).transform_bin(
    'd2_age_binned', field='d2_age'
).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count()',
    groupby=['d2_age_binned']
).transform_joinaggregate(
    in_group='count()',
    groupby=['d2_age_binned', '3_satisfied']
).transform_calculate(
    percentage=alt.datum.in_group / alt.datum.total
).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('d2_age_binned:Q', bin='binned'),
    alt.Y('3_satisfied'),
    alt.Size('percentage:Q', legend=alt.Legend(format='%', title='Percent in agegroup'))
)
```

[image]